# Config Tire to work with Bonsai ElasticSearch Heroku add-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, elasticsearch, tire

So I have a rails 3.2 app. I created an index. 
I followed this guide: https://gist.github.com/nz/2041121 to create an bonsai.rb file in `config/initializers/bonsai.rb`
It looks like this:

```
ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = ENV['BONSAI_URL']

# Optional, but recommended: use a single index per application per environment.
# Caveat: This convention not be entirely supported throughout Tire's API.
app_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore.dasherize
app_env = Rails.env
INDEX_NAME = "#{app_name}-#{app_env}"
```

But I dosent work, this outprint from the heroku logs:

```
2013-03-06T17:04:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SchoolsController#index as HTML
2013-03-06T17:04:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/trafikskola?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Malm%C3%B6" for 192.165.96.102 at 2013-03-06 17:04:54 +0000
2013-03-06T17:04:54+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"Malmö"}
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/trafikskola?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Malm%C3%B6 host=stormy-escarpment-2346.herokuapp.com fwd="192.165.96.102" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=3106ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/school.rb:19:in `search'
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:10:in `index'
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3073ms
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-06T17:04:58+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

**My questions:**

1. Should I put somehting in the `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` in the bonsai.rb file? If yes, then what?
2. I have created a local index to, does that mean something?
3. Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config/initializers/bonsai.rb` was right and the problem was I had to index it in production mode also.

So I did this:

```
heroku rake environment tire:import CLASS=School FORCE=true
```

And it worked.

Comment: Cool, notice, when you'd be connected via SSH on a regular host, you'd have to set Rails environment (`RAILS_ENV=production`).

Comment: Heroku will also remind you - `heroku rake` is deprecated in favor of `heroku run rake`