# Deploying rails app to heroku with elasticsearch, bonsai

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, elasticsearch, tire

I have pushed my app to heroku, and I'm having functionality issues with my search features. I'm using ElasticSearch with Tire, as well as the Bonsai addon for Heroku. I've created a bonsai.rb initializer per the documentation for Bonsai: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai#installing-the-add-on

It looks like this so far:

```
ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] = ENV['BONSAI_URL']
```

Here's the error I'm getting from Heroku logs when I try to run a search:

```
Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed (404 : {"error":"Index not found, and lazy index creation is disabled.
```

I had thought that Tire would create indexes automatically. To be honest, I'm a little unclear about what these indexes are. Are they the same as the indexes in my development database? Is anyone aware of a good guide or tutorial for deploying an app with these features? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooh, how cool - I get to actually be the first person to answer a question. So I *think* the underlying problem is that while Tire does create indexes automatically, it doesn't do so in the production environment. If you follow the instructions on the Heroku page on Bonsai, your production index will be named differently than your development index. So your production index won't contain documents, because it hasn't been set up already by Tire.

The solution, which worked for me, is described on [Config Tire to work with Bonsai ElasticSearch Heroku add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253773/config-tire-to-work-with-bonsai-elasticsearch-heroku-add-on):

```
heroku run rake environment tire:import CLASS=School FORCE=true
```

The value of the `CLASS` variable would be the name of your model, of course, not `School`.

To answer your second question - "what these indexes are" - they are search indexes, which function similarly to database indexes, but

- are stored on Bonsai's servers
- are architected to allow for fast keyword-based retrieval of "unstructured content"

That's a *very* high level summary of what "search indexes" are - start [here on this Wikipedia article on search indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_index) to learn all about the wonderful world of unstructured full-text search!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Sorry for the non-response, I haven't been developing for the past couple weeks. I'm going to try your solution here this week and I'll get back to you with the results.