# Elasticsearch returning 504 when trying to index on Heroku

Tags: heroku, elasticsearch, tire

I've added elasticsearch to my Rails app using [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) as outlined in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1?view=asciicast).

I've tried to deploy to Heroku with Bonsai add-on. After following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/2041121) and also using information w Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253773/config-tire-to-work-with-bonsai-elasticsearch-heroku-add-on), I've tried running this command:

```
heroku run rake environment tire:import CLASS=Document FORCE=true
```

(`Document` is, of course, the name of my model.)

But I keep getting this error message:

```
Running `rake environment tire:import CLASS=Document FORCE=true` attached to terminal... up, run.4773
[IMPORT] Deleting index 'documents'
[IMPORT] Creating index 'documents' with mapping:
{"document":{"properties":{}}}
[ERROR] There has been an error when creating the index -- Elasticsearch returned:
504 :
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might not have done anything wrong. Bonsai has been experiencing issues for the past 18 hours. Your 504 error may just be a result of this.

See this tweet: https://twitter.com/bonsaisearch/status/394950014361165824